# Delete special characters in malformed text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, encoding, nokogiri

I am encountering some malformed text, and can't seem to find a generalized way to remove the special characters.

This is the text as seen on the website: `Technological�\x00 Sciences`. `String#force_encoding('UTF-8')` results: `Technological\u0000 Sciences`, which still causes Nokogiri to terminate early.

I could do a quick and dirty gsub `"Technological\u0000 Sciences".gsub(/\u0000/,'')`, but was wondering if there was a more generalized solution, or a configuration in Nokogiri or ruby that would also work?

Comment: what is the desired output?

Comment: Maybe an encoding issue? How is the text rendered on the website when viewed in a browser?

Comment: The desired output is "Technological Sciences" so any special characters are deleted. This way Nokogiri can proceed as expected. This might be an encoding issue; I have not been successful trying to resolve it with `String#encode`.

Comment: *"... causes Nokogiri to terminate early"* - is an exception being raised?

Comment: No, an exception is not being raised, but no website content after the special character is parsed/returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
"Technological�\x00 Sciences".gsub(/[^[:alnum:][:space:][:punct:]]/, '')
```

Comment: I modified this to include other valid posix bracket expressions in my real code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
[29] pry(main)> str
=> "Technological�\u0000 Sciences"
[30] pry(main)> str.scan(/[a-zA-Z]{2,}/).join(' ')
=> "Technological Sciences"
```